# Cannot create Ctrl+Alt+Shift+@ shortcut key combination

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to have the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to start my scanner from the desktop (after having used the same in GIMP for years), but for some reason it is gone and I cannot recreate it. Keyboard is UK layout, and it's the <kbd>'</kbd> (<kbd>@</kbd>) key I'm trying to use.

Clicking on the shortcut key window followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> enters

```
CTRL + SHIFT + ALT +
```

in the box, and from here any letter `A`-`Z` or number `0`-`9` key works. as do many others like `[]-=,./;#`

However, as soon as I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, the dialog loses focus and the field reverts to `None`.

How can I get my old keyboard shortcut back?

Comment: Which version of Windows is in question?

Comment: W7-64 Pro, fully up-to-date with the exception of all "updates" that try to sell me W10.